How can I undo changes after clicking "Accept" in Cursor AI Code Editor?
I frequently use Cursor AI Code Editor's Composer feature to apply AI-suggested edits to my code. After reviewing the changes, I click Accept to apply them. However, sometimes I realize that I need to revert to the previous state before accepting the changes, but I couldn't find a built-in option in the editor to do so.
I tried searching for an Undo button or shortcut in Cursor after clicking Accept, but it doesn't seem to exist.
Currently, I rely on external version control tools like Git to manage rollbacks. While this works, it feels excessive for smaller changes.
Is there a native way within Cursor to undo changes after accepting edits, or are external tools the only solution?
Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated!
